# Adding Data from Database to Textbox - Jquery

Tags: jquery, sql, forms, textbox

I've created a dynamic list in Jquery, and when a user clicks on an item it brings them to a new page in which specific items to the list option they selected is shown. So far I have them showing up inside of various paragraph and headers  attributes and so on just for the sake of testing.

What I'm trying to do is get the data which is currently being displayed using them tags and instead place them inside text boxes within the form.

A sample of the Code rendering the data and submitting them to the attributes etc is:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).on('pagebeforeshow', '#index', function(){
        $("#list").empty();
        var url="http://localhost/test/login/json4.php";
        $.getJSON(url,function(json){
            //loop through deals
            $.each(json.deals,function(i,dat){
                $("#list").append("<li><a id='"+dat.dealid+"' data-restaurantid=" + dat.restaurantid + " data-image=" + dat.image + "><h1>"+dat.name+"</h1><p>"+dat.dname+"</p></a></li>");
                $(document).on('click', '#'+dat.dealid, function(event){  
                    if(event.handled !== true) // This will prevent event triggering more then once
                    {
                        dealObject.dealID = $(this).attr('id'); 
                        dealObject.restaurantid = $(this).attr('data-restaurantid');
                        dealObject.name = $(this).find('h1').html(); 
                        dealObject.image = $(this).attr('data-image');
                        //dealObject.dname = $(this).find('input').html();
                        dealObject.dname = $(this).find('input').val();

                        $.mobile.changePage( "#index2", { transition: "slide"} );
                        event.handled = true;
                    }
                });            
            });
            $("#list").listview('refresh');
        });
    });

    $(document).on('pagebeforeshow', '#index2', function(){       
        //$('#index2 [data-role="content"]').html('You have selected Link' + dealObject.dname);
        $('#index2 [data-role="content"]').find('#deal-img').attr('src',dealObject.dealObject);
        $('#index2 [data-role="content"]').find('#title').html(dealObject.name);
        //$('#index2 [data-role="content"]').find('#description').html(dealObject.dname);
        $('#index2 [data-role="content"]').find('#name').html(dealObject.dname);
    });

    var dealObject = {
        dealID : null,
        restaurantid : null,
        name : null,
        image : null,
        dname : null
    }    
</script>
```

Here's a snippit of the Index 2 html up to the end of the content div:

```
 <div data-role="page" id="index2">

<div data-role="header">
        <h1> Find A Deal </h1> 
    </div>

    <div data-role="content">

        <?php
    if( !isset( $_SESSION ) ){
     session_start();
        }

    if( isset( $_SESSION['username'] ) ){
        echo ".";
        } ?>   

        <label for="name">Deal Name:</label>
        <input type="text" value="" name="name" id="name"/>
        <label for="desc">Description</label>
        <input type="text" value="" name="desc" id="desc"/>  
        <a data-role="button" id="submit-button" data-theme="b">Submit</a>

        <img src="" width="100px" height="100px" id="deal-img">
        <h1 id="title"></h1>
        <h3 id="description"></h3>
        <p id="name"></p>
       </div>
```

Comment: I realize I'm only looking at a fragmented version, but it looks like you have to make "});"'s in your $(document).on('click') function....

Comment: That has been added alright, apologies, I didn't want to upload too much code to oversight the question. I have these data values rendering within '<h1>' and '<p>' and other tags like that no problem. It's just trying to get it to set to a textbox is where my issue is

Answer (score 0):

```
dealObject.dname = $(this).find('input').html();
```

You're setting it to the innerHTML of an input type='text' element? The innerHTML of an input type='text' element should always return as an empty string.

I think you should be using .val()

```
dealObject.dname = $(this).find('input').val();
```

Comment: Thanks @mirnber This unfortunately still hasn't worked out for me im afraid =/

Comment: Have you looked into what I said earlier? That it looks like you have too many "});"....is any message coming up in your browser's JS error console?

Comment: Not that I can see anyway, I'll ammend my question above and put in the full jscript code so you can see

Comment: Apologies - I think I've even just deleted half the question by mistake haha, long long day!

Comment: Yeah now the HTML disappeared. I wanna say using .val() should have been your answer if the h1 and p were showing up. Are you sure its not a jquery mobile cacheing issue? Have you tried refreshing two times per page hit instead of one? I know I've had problems with jquery mobile being really greedy about cacheing stuff

Comment: I just added the HTML there now again. Ya when I heard him suggest .val() I thought that's definitely it but just doesn't seem to be working which is weird.
Ya went refreshing loads of times and even went back to the start of this whole prcoess where I logged in as a user and still nothing! Cant figure it out at all =/

Answer (score 0):

Oh wait sorry I didn't look at it close enough....it's probably because there are multiple input type='text elements'...This means it's matching multiptle elements. To confirm my theory, you should be able to try this...

```
dealObject.dname = $(this).find('input').eq(0).val();
```

By adding the .eq(0) it should only do it to the first input type='text' element which is the one with id='name'

Comment: For the record and as a reminder to myself.... 
.find() can return multiple elements...not just one.

Comment: Still nothing I'm afraid =/

For something I thought would have been a small enough error or something is turning into a seriously impossible task haha!

Comment: Yeah well I'm all out of answers unless you wanna send a live link....Hope you get it figured out!

Comment: I've only begun teaching myself coding at the moment so I dont have this served or a bit, I'm just making it with localhost. I read somewhere else about the .val method so I wonder why it's not working for me. I'll keep up the search and tell you if I get anything working anyway!

Thanks so much for your time, I appreciate it :)

Answer (score 0):

Found your problem, name can not be used as a variable name inside a js object.

Change:

```
var dealObject = {
    dealID : null,
    restaurantid : null,
    name : null,
    image : null,
    dname : null
}
```

to something like this:

```
var dealObject = {
    dealID : null,
    restaurantid : null,
    shortname : null,
    image : null,
    dname : null
}
```

Also use this:

```
$('#index2 [data-role="content"]').find('input#desc').val(dealObject.description);
$('#index2 [data-role="content"]').find('input#name').val(dealObject.dealName);
$('#index2 [data-role="content"]').find('input#did').val(dealObject.dealID);
```